# can't install r-base 3.6.3 in linux mint

Tags: r, linux, linux-mint

If I run this

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

R 3.4 is installed from the ubuntu repo. So I added the CRAN repositories by doing

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base
```

but then I get

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base: Depends: r-base-core (> = 3.6.3-1eoan) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is going to be installed
         Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.3-1eoan) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is going to be installed
E: Problems cannot be corrected, you have retained broken packages.
```

I swear I tried every line of code from every forum I found but nothing solved this issue. I tried:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

I also tried disabling ubuntu repos and use only the CRAN repositories, but it doesnt work.
I tried installing r-base 3.4 and upgrading from that but nothing.

I really don't know what else to do, any ideas?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: I get a 404 response from `https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu%20eoan-cran35/`. Possibly you want: `https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/eoan-cran35/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend of the version of Linux Mint you are running, but based on your code, you are trying to install `r-base` for `Ubuntu 19.10 eoan` (which is not a LTS).

The last version of `Linux Mint 19.3` is based on `Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic`, so you should edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and add

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

All informations from `cran` are here: https://cran.r-project.org/

For Linux Mint, check this page (https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tricia_xfce_whatsnew.php):

*> Linux Mint 19.3 features Xfce 4.14, a Linux kernel 5.0 and an Ubuntu 18.04 package base.*